# JSON.parse error on simplejson return in Django

Tags: django, json, simplejson

I have a view page that currently has two columns of data shown, soon to be expanded to four.  Each column contains the result of a QuerySet for that particular model.

Here's what I have in my views.py method:

```
if request.REQUEST["type"] == "text":
        client = Client.objects.get(client_name = request.REQUEST["search"])
        peerList = ClientPeers.objects.prefetch_related().filter(client = client.client)
        compList = ClientCompetitors.objects.prefetch_related().filter(client = client.client)

else:
    peerList = ClientPeers.objects.prefetch_related().filter(client = request.REQUEST["search"])
    compList = ClientCompetitors.objects.prefetch_related().filter(client = request.REQUEST["search"])

for peer in peerList:
    peerlst.append({"pid" : peer.parentorg.parentorg, "pname" : peer.parentorg.parentorgname})

for comp in compList:
    complst.append({"cid" : comp.parentorg.parentorg, "cname" : comp.parentorg.parentorgname})

lst.append(simplejson.dumps(peerlst))
lst.append(simplejson.dumps(complst))

return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(lst), mimetype = "text/json")
```

This allows me to send a 2D array of data to the browser in the format

```
[ { //JSON }, { //JSON } ]
```

In my jQuery.ajax success function, I have

```
function handler(results) {
  var data = JSON.parse(results);

  for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++)
    $("#available_peers").append("<li>" + data[0][i].pname + "</li>");

  for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++)
    $("#available_competitors").append("<li>" + data[1][i].cname + "</li>");
```

Firebug shows that the GET request works and I can see the data in the response tab.  However, the console prints out

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
var data = JSON.parse(results)
```

This error disappears if I replace `var data = JSON.parse(results)` with

```
var peers = JSON.parse(data[0]);
var comps = JSON.parse(data[1]);
```

Why does one method work but another doesn't?

Comment: try changing text/json for application/json

Comment: What does the full `.ajax()` call look like?

Comment: What does the json data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call will make an intelligent guess as to the returned data type.  In your example, `function handler(results)`, the `results` variable will already be a decoded JSON object, containing two items in an array.  The reason that `JSON.parse(data[0])` works, is that you have returned JSON encoded data as a string.

Don't encode the individual list elements to JSON before placing in the output array:

```
lst.append(peerlst)  # <-- Don't encode to JSON string here
lst.append(complst)

return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(lst), mimetype = "application/json") # <-- Single JSON encoding
```